# Redirecionamento externo no express

Tags: node.js, http, express.js

Galera,

Como eu faço para trocar essa linha de código minha:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Para 1 redirecionamento externo, por exemplo redirecionar para

```
http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Será `res.redirect('http://www.google.com');`? Dentro da routa que quer que faça redirect

Comment: Porque razão queres dizer ao browser para ignorar ficheiros estáticos e usar um url externo? Se explicares o que queres fazer acho que vais ter ajuda mais acertada.

Comment: @Miguel esse res seria em qual lugar? na hora de iniciar o http?

Comment: Destro de uma rota, ora veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352871/in-express-how-do-i-redirect-a-user-to-an-external-url ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757061/route-client-to-external-site-in-node-js

Comment: @Sergio eu não vou utilizar a parte estática do meu app, eu passei ela para outro dominio e vou ficar só consumindo os serviços, pois preciso fazer várias coisas de URL amigavel e etc.

Comment: @Miguel entendi, ai essa linha no meu server.js que trata o static deixaria de existir, correto?

Comment: Eu acho que essa linha pode continuar, é só redirecionar onde quiser... Na rota que quiser

Comment: Não seria caso de usar o `<base>`? Se não estás a ir ao servidor para retornar um redirect e é mais demorado.